# OpenStak Security Monitoring

Tags: security, logging, monitoring, openstack

I am looking for some advise about tools for openstack monitoring. This is a project that I am looking to take on and try out. You advise is much appreciated.

I am looking for software/application that I can install on my OpenStack to allow monitoring of security events.

In particular, I am trying to look into virtual machine monitoring, SLA based monitoring, Event based monitoring and Policy Based Monitoring.

Note, I am not really interested in resource allocation or usage. Any advise on existing tools that I can try would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenStack docs](http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/logging_monitoring.html) and the [OpenStack wiki](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Operations/Monitoring) seem to have some good recommendations. However, this question might be better suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), and you would likely get better answers posting there.